# Jquery scrollTo Plugin: Scroll to an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm using the scrollTo plugin (http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) to scroll to a specific anchor in my page. Now I would like to be able to specify an anchor to scroll to, so I tried this:

```
$('a[name="anchorname"]').scrollTo();
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for

```
$.scrollTo('a[name="anchorname"]');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/davUw/

Comment: Yes, Thanks - my bad, I didn't read the documentation properly.

Comment: I think it's good idea to add `:first` at the end of the selector